# How do I check if a member of an array matches any member of another array using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to continuously check whether one of a number of processes is running.  So far I've used:

```
Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcesses();
```

to get the currently running processes.  I have a string array containing the list of processes I want to make sure aren't running before I continue:

```
string[] ProcessesToCheck = new string[] {"Chartvue",
        "collvue"
        ,"damage"
        ,"Datagen"
        ,"datagenlegacy"
        ,"FAST_SACS"
        ,"hullmesher"
        ,"hullmodeler"
        ,"ifatigue"};
```

The question is, how to I check that all ProcessName members of Processes does not contain any member of ProcessesToCheck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the process names into an hashset (for a faster lookup) then use `Any` method to check if any of the process names is present in `ProcessesToCheck`

```
var processNames = new HashSet<string>(Processes.Select(p => p.ProcessName));
bool isExists = ProcessesToCheck.Any(processNames.Contains);
```

Comment: processNames.Contains means??

Comment: @neel it is a method group. shorthand for `ProcessesToCheck.Any(x => processNames.Contains(x));`

Comment: ... and it is actually an extension method, `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(processNames, x)`, but it still works to use the method group syntax. ***Edit:*** When `processNames` has type `HashSet<string>`, that is an ordinary instance method. I thought you had type `string[]` ...

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var isExists = Processes.Any(x => ProcessesToCheck.Contains(x.ProcessName));
```

In the above code we use the method `Any` to see if there exists at least one process in the array `Processes`, whose property called `ProcessName` is contained in the array called `ProcessesToCheck`.

For more information about `Any`, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) and for more information about `Contains`, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).ASPX).